# how to send location map in android

Tags: android, database, google-maps, location

I'm trying to add a feature in my app in Android and that is to send my location just like it's done on whatsapp or viber.
I know how to retrieve my location either via google maps or coordinates via provider, but can anyone help me get started in how to actually send the map of my location? possibly to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- after you get the location using locationManager you can store the values lat/long in variables.

2- store variables in json object.

3- POST json using HTTP request

on web page

1- handle json response

2- store values in variables

3- view the map by putting the variables in the code given by google maps API